# Правописание "не" с прилагательными

Tags: частица

В данном контексте "Двойная ткань-сетка делает кресло не(?)прозрачным" частица "не" пишется раздельно с прилагательным? Применимо ли правило, согласно которому  прилагательное с "не" в функции сказуемого передает общеотрицательный смысл предложения и потому пишется раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В данном контексте "Двойная ткань-сетка делает кресло не(?)прозрачным" частица "не" пишется раздельно с прилагательным?

Нет. Здесь почти наверняка - новое качество "непрозрачность", поэтому слитно.

> Применимо ли правило, согласно которому прилагательное с "не" в функции сказуемого передает общеотрицательный смысл предложения и потому пишется раздельно?

Правило такое есть (хотя лучше по-другому немного формулировать), но к данной фразе не имеет никакого отношения. Непрозрачный - это не сказуемое. Вот если бы "не делает прозрачным", некоторые основания для применения такого правила были бы. Но и в этом случае - чисто академические, ибо "**не** с глаголами пишется раздельно", а это куда проще запомнить и применить.